# Count column without grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, sql-server-2019

Below is my 1st Table1

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | Cell 2 |
| A | Cell 4 |
| B | Cell 2 |
| A | Cell 4 |
| B | Cell 2 |
| A | Cell 4 |

Below is my result that I want to achieve based on Table1
I need column C in select query which gives the count of number of time it appears in column A in each row of column C. I am using SQL Server.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Cell 2 | 4 |
| A | Cell 4 | 4 |
| B | Cell 2 | 2 |
| A | Cell 4 | 4 |
| B | Cell 2 | 2 |
| A | Cell 4 | 4 |

I have tried below query but due to groupby clause it is showing only two rows which is not my desired result

```
Select ColumnA, Count(ColumnA) as ColumnC
from Table1
group By columnA
```

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| B | 2 |

Comment: Usually, just posting a desired result is not sufficient for Stack Overflow. Instead you should show your efforts and ask on which point you struggle. See also "[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: use Analytic function syntax of [COUNT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: @Squirrel its asking for group by clause and it is grouping my column A and showing the result in single rows, I want to show the count in each row. If you can give me the query it will be helpfull

Comment: @UweKeim Ok sir, since I am the beginner I was not much aware of, I'll keep your guidance in my mind for the next time. I am using below query but due to group by clause i cannot active what I want. Select ColumnA,Column(B), Count(ColumnA) as ColumnC from Table1 group By columnA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the result using Partition

I have tried below solution

```
SELECT ColumnA
    , ColumnB
    , Count(ColumnB) OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnA) as Intensity
FROM [dbo].[Table1]
```

| Column A | Column B | Intensity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Cell 2 | 4 |
| A | Cell 4 | 4 |
| B | Cell 2 | 2 |
| A | Cell 4 | 4 |
| B | Cell 2 | 2 |
| A | Cell 4 | 4 |

Comment: `Count(ColumnB)` counts non-null values of `ColumnB` you could also use `COUNT(*)` in your case.

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the feedback mate. But what if my column is not allowing null values? In that case query will be fine right?

Comment: Then you might as well do `COUNT(*) OVER (....`